# Does bleach kill flea eggs?

Tags: cats, fleas, parasites, pest-control

Context: I'm having an issue with fleas in the apartment. I have three adult cats, which I bathe every 6 weeks more or less. Back 3 months ago, they got fleas from the outside. I used Frontline Plus that one time only, washed all blankets and vacuumed the house prior to cleaning. After cleaning I used a common household inseticide on the corners and near the walls. (Of course I kept the cats in another room for the day) and everything appeared to be fine.

But this week I discovered fleas again. Since I'm not walking the cats outside anymore, I think some hidden flea eggs have survived and now they've hatched.

Apart from a new Frontline round, I'm thinking about doing a *very thorough* cleaning with water, detergent and bleach (sodium hypochlorite) in the entire apartment. But I'm in doubt whether it's effective in cleaning flea eggs. My search on the subject has proven inconclusive.

The question, like in the title, is whether bleach kills flea eggs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes germicidal bleach will kill flea eggs on hard surfaces and in laundry, but the trick with hard surfaces is getting into the nooks and crannies where you can't see. If you have tested a small amount on the hard surfaces first, you may want to consider doing a soaking.. to let it sit and seep into cracks. When using it in laundry use co!Or safe bleach Instead of detergent.

Keep in mind bleach is harmful to pets if digested and strong fumes from bleach are harmful to their respiratory system. A thorough rinsing is important and plenty of ventilation in your home at the time of use, as well as diluting the bleach with water are all important tips for pet safety.

Here's a link on how to use bleach to kill eggs: 
https://www.hunker.com/12442407/does-bleach-kill-flea-eggs

Comment: As a feedback, I was very successfull in solving the problem, with your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Fleas have a reproduction rate of 30 days. If you eradicate 1 generation the eggs may still survive. In order to prevent this you have to repeat the process of getting rid of them at least once after 30 days...

Answer (score 2):

The Short answer; Using bleach to fight flea infestation is not worthwhile your effort especially when cats are involved. You must get every surface, nook and cranny which is not possible in a traditional home.

Long version: Most household or yard insecticides are very toxic to cats, they often contain a variation of pyrethroid under many confusing trade names. These will destroy a cats liver, period.

When dealing with an active infestation, you need to use a combination product for about six month such as frontline plus (fipronil+S-Methoprene) or nitenpyram (capstar) and S-Methoprene (hartz ultragard).

The reason you have to use the medicine 6 months continuously is because fleas can form a cocoon in a dust ball or in a lint and hibernate up to 6 months embedded in carpet or under seat cushions. Vacuum all you want, you can't suck them all. However frequent vacuuming helps a lot.

Don't confuse the flea cocoon with flea eggs or larva. When conditions are right, fleas jump out of their cocoon and resume their activity and the cycle begins all over. This is why you need to use a combination product with hormone disruptors like S-Methoprene. It acts like birth control pill for fleas.

The 2 chemicals nitenpyram and S-Methoprene have been in use for a long time with good safety and efficacy there for they are one of the safer combinations to both cats and humans. Keep in mind, even table salt can be lethal.

Reduce exposure to fleas by keeping cats indoors. Vacuum frequently. Apply S-Methoprene during warm season and when there's an active infestation supplement with nitenpyram for a week or two.